# Left click selection deselect object (2.8)

Tags: interface

I was astonished when I heard the announcement of left Click by Default. Anyway 
I gave it a try and it felt familiar. but I got stuck when it came to adding objects to the current selection. Ok now I know shift+CTRl left Clicking ads new objects to my selection (why not shift or CTRL). But I have no idea how to deselect one object from the selection.

Can you help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about unfinished features of experimental versions of Blender

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you:

*Left Click and drag = Select the objects.

*Ctrl + Left click and drag = Deselect.

*Shift + Left Click = Add Objects to the selection.

*Shift + Double Left Click on an object = Deselect

[image]

Hope that helps.

Good Luck.

Comment: OP is looking for "how to deselect one object from the selection"

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+LeftClick adds an object to the selection if it isn't already selected. The same action removes an object from the selection if it is already selection.

ie, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+LeftClick can be used to deselect an already selected object.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm on mac)
double tap on <kbd>A</kbd> does the trick for me